# How to update a MySQL record with a NULL value using AG-Grid valueSetter?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ag-grid, node-mysql2

this isnt doing the trick. no error is produced on the console, but refreshing the page just brings back the previous value. replacing `null` with any other data befitting the column works as intended.

```js
valueSetter: params => {
  params.data.column = null;
  return true;
}
```

just for fun, ive also tried the following. but no update occurs and no error appears on the console.

```js
valueSetter: async params => {
  await pool.query("UPDATE table SET column = NULL WHERE otherColumn = 'value';");
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears to require a combination of both my previous attempts in the following order.

```js
valueSetter: params => {
  params.data.column = null;
  await pool.query("UPDATE table SET column = NULL WHERE otherColumn = 'value';");
  return true;
}
```